# Why is [] = _. true in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog, and do not understand why `?- [] = _.` returns true in SWI-Prolog. 
`[]` means an empty list, and `_` means it is not empty, right?
Could someone explain the above logic?

Comment: An arbitrary and anonymous non-empty list would be represented by `[_|_]`, which is a list with an anonymous head and an anonymous tail. `_` by itself unifies with anything. `1 = _.`, `a(b,c) = _.` and `x = _.` are also all true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`_` is a logical variable, just like `X` or anything else that starts with an underscore or a capital letter. Free variables (i.e., variables that are not already bound to some term) can be unified with anything. A goal like `[] = X` says "unify `X` with `[]`", with the effect that, if this succeeds, every use of `X` will refer to the term `[]`.

With `_` as the variable this is the same as for `X`, with the exception that `_` is the *anonymous* variable: It cannot be reused, its name does not matter, and different occurrences of `_` refer to different variables. So `_` can never be bound before encountering the goal `[] = _`. Thus this unification succeeds, which is why you get the answer `true`.

`_` does not by itself mean "not empty". But you may be confused by its use as a placeholder: `L = [_,_,_]` means that `L` is a list of three elements (that we know nothing about). In this sense `_` means "there is something here". But it has to be *inside* the list for this meaning.